# Adding a objective-c framework into another module in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on an app where I have to divide the app into modules based on Features. App has both Swift and Objective-c languages.

In the app,  I already have another third party Framework written in Objective-C. Before modularization, I created a bridging header and added the third party framework.

Now when I created Modules for each feature then I found I can't use bridging header, so I created I different module for Objective-C framework.

Now Structure is Like below

```
  ThirdPartyModule (added Objective-C framowrk)
  Module1  (import ThirdPartyModule)
  Module2 
  Module3
  Module4 (import ThirdPartyModule)
  Module5 (import ThirdPartyModule)
Main App (Import Module1,Module2, Module3, Module4,Module5 )
```

But when I am trying to compile Module1 or  Module4, I am getting the following error

> Could not build Objective-C module 'ModuleName'

Can you please help me how to fix this issue.

Please let me know If I have to explain my question more.

Comment: Please describe how you installed those modules. Carthage, Pods, Manual, etc.

Comment: I did manual installation.

Comment: Did you set ThirdPartyModule to "Link Binary With Libraries" Section in Module1, 4, 5 Target?

Comment: yes, I did the linking .